# Wordpress with Fancybox and Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, fancybox

In wordpress i use fancybox for display contact for and now i have to submit this form using ajax but ajax is not call in wordpress. i try it outside of wordpress package its working fine .
Please help for solving this.

```
<script>
function sendMail()
{
    alert("call");
var name1=document.getElementById("txtName").value;
var surname1=document.getElementById("txtSurname").value;
var contact1=document.getElementById("txtContact").value;
var email1=document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
var comment1=document.getElementById("txtComment").value;
var subject1=document.getElementById("txtSubject").value;
jQuery.ajax({
 type: "POST",
url:  "sendMail.php",
data: { name: name1, surname:surname1,contact:contact1,email:email1,comment:comment1,subject:subject1,oper:"send" }
}).done(function( msg ) 
{     
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
```

This my apply.php file which open in fancy box and i call this function using button click but its worked in outside wordpress not in wordpress please help me for solving this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that Jquery is not loaded at that time. Do you have errors in browser console? On chrome press F12.

Comment: Thanks for reply its loaded successfully